# Cannot perform = operation between int32 and string. datarow filter

Tags: c#, sql, dataview

First of all I apologies for the paraphrasing I will be doing, I do not have access to my code right now and am on my phone but wanted to get this posted so that when I do have access later I hopefully have an answer. If i don't I will obviously update the question with actual exerts from it.

Relevant details of my problem:
I am passing a string variable to a method

Inside the method using the variable as a filter value for a dataview

The dataview column I am filtering by is varchar

I get an error about not being able to perform = operations with int32 and string

So as far as I know varchar are strings, my variable is passed as a string so also must be one.

I have definately got the syntax and usage of the filtering correct as I have been using it in plenty of other places with no issue and examined this extensively.

Is there some weird behaviour when using all statements and either the view column values are "only numeric" varchar or the variable is "only numeric" ? it seems odd that this could have an effect .... A string is a string right?

I have tried using the convert SQL command on the column and using .tostring() on the variable. This did not work and even if it did I would still want an explanation as to why 2 strings are behaving like one is an int.

A rough usage though the syntax could be wrong here as it's from memory (so if it is then assume it's correct ...see above)

```
MyDataView.filter = "MyColumnnName = " + MyVariable;
```

From my research so far some people suggest putting "... + MyVariable + ""; " I have tried this and get the same error.

Many thanks!

Comment: There's no difference between `"MyColumnnName = " + MyVariable` and `"MyColumnnName = " + MyVariable  + ""`

Comment: You need to use `CONVERT` function. Please refer the duplicate link just about your question..

Comment: String values are enclosed within single quotes `' '`. So  like: `"MyColumnnName = '" + MyVariable + "'"`

Comment: @TimSchmelter - This is what i thought but i had seen it as a suggestion so thought i'd mention i had tried it so as not to receive it as a solution... However i also mentioned that i had used CONVERT and it hadn't helped and was sill pointed to this a a solution :( In addition i wanted a reason why this behavior occurred....

Comment: @Tim in essence: I had presumed as much but wanted to ensure i had listed everything i had already tried. As this is a solution posted on similar questions i mentioned it (knowing that it should make no difference)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel "However i also mentioned that i had used CONVERT and it hadn't helped and was sill pointed to this a a solution :( In addition i wanted a reason why this behavior occurred.... " was for you

Comment: @user3688581 Oops. I'm sorry. I didn't noticed that. If you claim that `Convert` doesn't work please post that code also. I'll reopen you question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter so weirdly the solution was the single quotes.... as suggested by TIm. I initially disregarded this as my other filters do not use them and work fine. Any explanation? in my other filters i am using "... + Variable.tostring(); " could this be an explanation? does to string somehow compensate for the lack of single quote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String` values have to be enclosed within single quotes `' '`. So like:

```
MyDataView.filter = "MyColumnnName = '" + MyVariable + "'";
```

If it's not a string column you can omit them:

```
MyDataView.filter = "MyColumnnName = " + MyVariable;
```

But i'd use Linq-To-DataTable anyway:

```
DataTable filtered = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("MyColumnnName ") == MyVariable)
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

That is much easier to maintain and also much more powerful since you can use all .NET methods (or your own).